# create shell command dynamically from a query string in node js

Tags: node.js

I want to run the above code and change the query string dynamically,

when I put this line in the code "comandd = `sh /mypath/1.sh`"   **hardcoded**, it works fine,

but when I put this line in the code "comandd = `sh /mypath/` +  queryObject.num + `.sh`" it gives me "sh /mypath/**undefined**.sh"

This is The desired behavior:

http://localhost:8889/t.js?qs1=**1**  to run "sh /mypath/**1**.sh" shell on local server

http://localhost:8889/t.js?qs1=**2**  to run "sh /mypath/**2**.sh" shell on local server

http://localhost:8889/t.js?qs1=**3**  to run "sh /mypath/**3**.sh" shell on local server

this is the code in t.js

```
const http = require('http');
const url = require('url');
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
var output1 = "";
var comandd = "";

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  const queryObject = url.parse(req.url,true).query;
  //console.log(queryObject.qs1);
  
  //comandd = `sh /mypath/1.sh`;   //this run fine
  comandd = `sh /mypath/` +  queryObject.qs1 + `.sh`;
 

  exec( comandd , (error, stdout, stderr) => {
    if (error) {
        output1 = `error: ${error.message}`;
        return;
    }
    if (stderr) {
        output1 =`stderr: ${stderr}`;
        return;
    }
    output1 = `Name: ${stdout}`;
});


  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
  res.write(output1);
  res.end();
}).listen(8889);
```

Comment: You didn't call your query parameter `num` you called it `qs1`.  `url.parse('http://localhost:8889/t.js?qs1=2', true).query.qs1` should be `2`

Comment: yes, when I anonymized the code I had a mistake, I fixed it now but it is still the same problem, thanks for your  comment

Comment: This is called a [child process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process) in nodejs, for your information.

Comment: The most obvious reason is that `queryObject.qs1` is indeed undefined. Enable the earlier console log. What does it log? If not that, then a second possible reason is that you're still not showing us the actual code that causes these symptoms.

Comment: it gives me:    1  and  undefined, maybe it calls the console twice

Comment: I run the code with "node t.js" this is all the code to run, I only changed "mypath" in the code .

Comment: Logged twice you say?  Are you doing this from a browser?  It's probably requesting your url (e.g.: `http://localhost:8889?qs1=2`) and then the favicon.  (`http://localhost:8889/favicon.ico`) which will have no query string and hence produce `undefined`.  Both requests will find their way to your requestListener ([read the docs](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_createserver_options_requestlistener) or `console.log(req.url)` at the top of the handler)  Are you open to using *express* to handle the routing in a better way?